# Porting from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12: how to get SSL connection info?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, jetty-12

With Jetty 11 I was able to get info about SSL session and client certificate by:

```
SSLSession sslSession = (SSLSession)request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session");
java.security.cert.X509Certificate client_certs[] = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But with Jetty 12 I see only two request attributes:

- `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.Cookies`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.server.x509` with server certificate

I am interested in attributes like:

- `ssl_protocol=TLSv1.3`
- `ssl_cipher=TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`
- `ssl_client_i_dn=CN=xyz`
- `x_ssl_client_cert=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIID8DCCAtigAwIBAgICA3wwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEwx ...`

How can I get those attributes with Jetty 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` and `SecureRequestCustomizer` does the work of pulling the information out and making it available via the Request object.

Eg:

```java
HttpConnectionFactory http = new HttpConnectionFactory();
http.getHttpConfiguration().addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
http.getHttpConfiguration().addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, http);
```

The `Request` object will be populated with the details you are looking for.

```java
request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.cipher_suite");
request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.ssl_session_id");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.cipher");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.keySize");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.sslSessionId");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.peerCertificates");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.x509");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.sslSession");
request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.sslSessionData");
request.getConnectionMetaData().getRemoteSocketAddress();
request.getConnectionMetaData().getServerAuthority();
request.isSecure();
request.getHttpURI();
request.getHeaders(); // updates the `Host` or `:authority` fields
```

Alternatively, you can pull it out of the jetty-core `Request` object.

```java
EndPoint endPoint = request.getConnectionMetaData().getConnection().getEndPoint();
if (endPoint instanceof SslEndPoint sslEndPoint)
{
    SslConnection sslConnection = sslEndPoint.getSslConnection();
    SSLEngine sslEngine = sslConnection.getSSLEngine();
    // TODO: get information out of the sslEngine
}
```

Comment: I used customizers and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: In Jetty 12.0.4 I have to use `request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.io.Endpoint.SslSessionData");`